# Show DataGridView's first row (scroll up to first row)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my DataGridView control I want to go to first row when user hits `Home` button.

I caught the keyDown event and here's the code:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
{
    dgvMain.FirstDisplayedCell = dgvMain.Rows[0].Cells[0];
}
```

does not work, nor does this one :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
{
    dgvMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvMain.Rows[0].Index;
}
```

these codes make grid scroll up a bit but not to the first row.

How can I focus on first Row? Without selecting it.

Comment: @Damith Refreshing does not help, did not. But when I set the Handled to true it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found were the problem was. I still don't understand why, but handling the event made it work:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    dgvMain.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
}
```

`Home` does not do anything (AFAIK) but when I handle it everything is ok. Why? I don't know.

Comment: I really appreciate people who answer their own questions as soon as they found the solution. :) It will be annoying if we found someone faced the same issue as someone but no answers even after they found the answer :(

Comment: StackOverflow is the biggest online Q&A resource for programmers, so providing answers are as important as finding them. Thanks @SriramSakthivel.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari - The `HOME` key is handled by `DataGridView` for navigating to the first cell in a row when the SelectionMode is CellSelect. In this case pressing `END` key moves to the last cell of the row.

Comment: @Junaith thanks didn't know that. I knew something should be done when `Home` is pressed but as long as I was using RowSelect as SelectionMode I could not feel what happens. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari - Welcome. Also since you have mentioned you are using RowSelect, in that case `Home` navigates to the first row and `End` navigates to last row. I was wondering why you have overridden the default behavior of the DataGridView.

Comment: @Junaith don't know why, but it did not do anything when I pressed `Home` button, and yes it is `FullRowSelect`.